# Find the points in the graph where the X coordinates is zero

Tags: java, jfreechart

I think that the Title of this question does not explain clearly my question, I'll explain it better.

I have a Java program that plot graphs using JFreeChart. Now I need to do something to get these points from the graph:

[image]

In these points, the X coordinate is zero. But none of these points I used to create the graph, so I'm confused if its possible to get them.

Can anyone give me some ideas to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your line is defined by a sequence of (x, y) points, you know that the line crossed x = 0 when two consecutive points have x-values of different sign. Then you can determine the value of y where the line crosses x = 0. Assuming linear interpolation between two consecutive points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), x1 * x2 < 0:

```
y0 = y2 - x2 * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)
```

Comment: In addition to Rémi's comments you need to decide if the `XYSplineRenderer` is the connect choice or if an `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` is correct - it will depend on your data.  If you should be using a `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` then you can use liner interpolation.